# Search query for empty\null string field in Azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Hi I have a string field which can be empty\null for certain documents. I like to know how to search for  those documents.

I want to know thru searchquery and not ODatFilter as I may like to solve following cases:

1. searching for empty\null in this field A
2. searching for substring in this field A( Eg: A:test)
3. searching for both empty\null or values containing test.

So ODataFilter suggestions will not help in achieving #2 so #1 should be using searchQuery.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can actually combine OData filters with search queries using the [`search.ismatch` or `search.ismatchscoring` functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-query-odata-full-text-search-functions). These functions let you embed full-text search queries inside a filter, which would allow you to address all your scenarios:

1. `$filter=A ne null`
2. `$filter=A ne null and search.ismatchscoring('A:test', null, 'full', null)` or equivalently, `$filter=A ne null&search=A:test&queryType=full`
3. `$filter=A eq null or search.ismatchscoring('A:test', null, 'full', null)` -- this can only be achieved with filters and `search.ismatch`/`search.ismatchscoring` because of the "or" operator.

The filter `A ne null` in case 2 above is actually redundant since nulls won't match any full-text search query, but in case 3 where you want to match nulls, filters are the way to do it.